# How to create an efficient heuristic for the Tour of the Horse, that solves matrices of 200 x 200?

Tags: backtracking

Develop a heuristic that allows you to find a
solution to the horse problem in the shortest time
possible.

This is the code I have, but it's not working and I don't understand why? And the heuristics should be fast to give the solution in seconds.

I look forward to your help, I would really appreciate it.

```
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(100000000)

Fil, Col, ii, jj = map(int, input().split())


def esValido(i, j):
    global Fil
    global Col
    return i >= 0 and i < Fil and j >= 0 and j < Col


def matNula(n, m):
    mtr = []
    for _ in range(n):
        subl = []
        for _ in range(m):
            subl.append(0)
        mtr.append(subl)
    return mtr


def kt(Fil, Col, ii, jj):
    pila = [[[ii, jj]]]
    while (pila != []):
        ruta = pila.pop()
        if (len(ruta) == Fil * Col): return ruta
        for hijo in hijos(ruta):
            pila.append(hijo)


def hijos(ruta):
    r = []
    MC = [[-2, -1], [-1, -2], [1, -2], [2, -1], [2, 1], [1, 2], [-1, 2], [-2, 1]]
    ult = ruta[-1]
    x = ult[0]
    y = ult[1]
    posibles_movimientos = []
    for i, j in MC:
        a = x + i
        b = y + j
        if esValido(a, b) and [a, b] not in ruta:
            num_movimientos = 0
            for k, l in MC:
                c = a + k
                d = b + l
                if esValido(c, d) and [c, d] not in ruta:
                    num_movimientos += 1
            posibles_movimientos.append((num_movimientos, a, b))
    # Ordenar por número de posibles movimientos
    posibles_movimientos.sort()
    for _, a, b in posibles_movimientos:
        r.append(ruta + [[a, b]])
    return r



def cabaTour(Fil, Col, i, j):
    mtr = matNula(Fil, Col)
    H = kt(Fil, Col, i, j)
    s = 1
    for a, b in H:
        mtr[a][b] = s
        s += 1
    return mtr


def muestraMatriz(mat):
    for fila in mat:
        for elemento in fila:
            print("{:04d}".format(elemento), end=" ")
        print()


muestraMatriz(cabaTour(Fil, Col, ii, jj))
```

Comment: What is "the tour of the horse"?  When you use a debugger, what is the *first* line that doesn't do what you expected?